# awk command to print substrings with values from separate file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a number of files which look like (PF.table):

```
Pyrococcus_furiosus_COM1_XCP003685_1    5   15
Pyrococcus_furiosus_COM1_XCP003685_2    20  24
Pyrococcus_furiosus_COM1_XCP003685_3    40  58
```

and associated sequence file (PF.seq):

```
ctgaggcgacatacgtttgagatacctggcaggtgatatgcaatgaggaaaaaacttgttggaatattgacaatattggttgctttgggcatgttagtaagccc....
```

I have been struggling to write a command to output a file which isolates substrings of length 5 starting at the character positions indicated by values in the first file.
The perfect output would be:

```
>Pyrococcus_furiosus_COM1_XCP003685_1_up
cgaca
>Pyrococcus_furiosus_COM1_XCP003685_1_down
gtttg
>Pyrococcus_furiosus_COM1_XCP003685_2_up
agata
...
```

The numbers in the table correspond to the position of a specific feature in the sequence, and I would like to extract the 5 characters upstream and downstream of said feature.
I'm really struggling to figure out how to pass the two files through awk! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '
  NR==FNR{ seq=$0; next }
  {
    print ">" $1 "_up"
    print substr(seq, $2, 5)
    print ">" $1 "_down"
    print substr(seq, $3, 5)
  }
' PF.seq PF.table
```

Output:

```
>Pyrococcus_furiosus_COM1_XCP003685_1_up
ggcga
>Pyrococcus_furiosus_COM1_XCP003685_1_down
gtttg
>Pyrococcus_furiosus_COM1_XCP003685_2_up
agata
>Pyrococcus_furiosus_COM1_XCP003685_2_down
acctg
>Pyrococcus_furiosus_COM1_XCP003685_3_up
gcaat
>Pyrococcus_furiosus_COM1_XCP003685_3_down
gttgg
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel so stupid - I was trying to do things in a completely backward order, loading the table to an array then accessing the sequence in the second step, rather than loading the sequence to a variable and accessing the table in the second step.